# Emberjs project and Visual Studio / Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ember-cli

I'm trying to develop my Ember.js application (created with ember-cli) using Visual Studio however each time, after a few seconds IDE crashes. The same happens with Visual Studio Code. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you excluding the `.tmp` folder?

Comment: I'm not. I don't know how to do that - such option doesn't exist when I open the window for loading a website into VS.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/1997766.aspx) is still applicable .

Answer (score 0):

This because ember has long folder names but in windows it has limit. Therefore most of the times visual studio will crash. Currently we are using inteliJ on linux. Intelij will never crash because linux doesn’t have limitation for the folder name